# Scale an image which is stored as a byte[] in Java

Tags: java, image, image-scaling

I upload a file with a struts form. I have the image as a byte[] and I would like to scale it.

```
FormFile file = (FormFile) dynaform.get("file");
byte[] fileData = file.getFileData(); 
fileData = scale(fileData,200,200);

public byte[] scale(byte[] fileData, int width, int height) {
// TODO 
}
```

Anyone knows an easy function to do this?

```
public byte[] scale(byte[] fileData, int width, int height) {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
            if(height == 0) {
                height = (width * img.getHeight())/ img.getWidth(); 
            }
            if(width == 0) {
                width = (height * img.getWidth())/ img.getHeight();
            }
            Image scaledImage = img.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            BufferedImage imageBuff = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            imageBuff.getGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, new Color(0,0,0), null);

            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            ImageIO.write(imageBuff, "jpg", buffer);

            return buffer.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ApplicationException("IOException in scale");
        }
    }
```

If you run out of Java Heap Space in tomcat as I did, increase the heap space which is used by tomcat. In case you use the tomcat plugin for Eclipse, next should apply:

> In Eclipse, choose Window >
>   Preferences > Tomcat > JVM Settings
>
> Add the following to the JVM
>   Parameters section
>
> -Xms256m -Xmx512m

Comment: __Guessing here__ : JPEG doesn't do transparency.  Change the `TYPE_INT_ARGB` to `TYPE_INT_RGB` and `new Color(0,0,0,0)` to `new Color(0,0,0)`

Comment: As for heap space, you could save some of space by working directly on an input stream instead of reading it into a byte array.  However, to scale an image you need a copy of it (and its scaled version) in memory; so you might just have to increase heap space.  Look into `java -xmx`.

Answer (score 26):

Depends on the data format.

However, if you're using something like JPEG, GIF, PNG, or BMP you can use the [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class.

Something like:

```
public byte[] scale(byte[] fileData, int width, int height) {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
    try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
        if(height == 0) {
            height = (width * img.getHeight())/ img.getWidth(); 
        }
        if(width == 0) {
            width = (height * img.getWidth())/ img.getHeight();
        }
        Image scaledImage = img.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        BufferedImage imageBuff = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        imageBuff.getGraphics().drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, new Color(0,0,0), null);

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ImageIO.write(imageBuff, "jpg", buffer);

        return buffer.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ApplicationException("IOException in scale");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, update your code with the tested code i posted in my question. I will clean the question, and accept your answer.

Comment: @Kevin Montrose shouldn't you close the open streams after resizing ?

Comment: ImageIO link is not available now. I want to know the dependency. Please let me know if it is still functioning.

Answer (score 2):

See this:

[Java 2D - How to convert byte[] to BufferedImage](http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=757947&messageID=4330508)

Then see this:

[How can I resize an image using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library)