# resize jpeg image in java

Tags: java, image-processing

i am working on image comparison in java. I think before going to compare the images, it is better to process the images for setting a fixed size image. Is there any java functionality to resize the images. I want to rescale the images to 300*225.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ImageIcon resizeImage(String filePath, int w, int h) {


        String data = filePath;
        BufferedImage bsrc, bdest;
        ImageIcon theIcon;

//scale the image
        try
        {

            bsrc = ImageIO.read(new File(data));

            bdest = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g = bdest.createGraphics();
            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance((double) w / bsrc.getWidth(),
                    (double) h / bsrc.getHeight());
            g.drawRenderedImage(bsrc, at);

            //add the scaled image
            theIcon = new ImageIcon(bdest);
            return theIcon;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("This image can not be resized. Please check the path and type of file.");
            return null;
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
Image scaled = img.getScaledInstance(300, 255, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

You can also take a look at the [java-image-scaling](https://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/wiki/Getting_started) library.

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedImage createResizedCopy(Image originalImage, 
                int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight, 
                boolean preserveAlpha)
{
    int imageType = preserveAlpha ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
    BufferedImage scaledBI = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, imageType);
    Graphics2D g = scaledBI.createGraphics();
    if (preserveAlpha) {
            g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    }
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null); 
    g.dispose();
    return scaledBI;
}
```

- [This threads answers your question well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library)
- [Very interesting article on manipulating images](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/)