# Image is not fully shown in JLabel using setIcon Method

Tags: java, swing, awt

Hello
I am setting image to JLabel as below

```
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(PathToImage,"Image");
jLabel4.setIcon(icon);
```

I have set label size as 5cm x5 cm square.
Whenever i am setting icon to Jlabel it is not shown fully .. only part of image is shown in jlabel.
How to solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: "5cm x5 cm"  That makes no sense at all.  What did you do, measure it on your screen?

Comment: @Andrew :: Actually i want to tell size of label so I described it like that .. now I have seen its size through properties and its 174x150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have scaled image using [java-image-scaling][1]

[1]: http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/ Library.

With scaling image is very simple just need to add two lines

`ResampleOp  resampleOp = new ResampleOp (100,200); 
BufferedImage rescaledTomato = resampleOp.filter(tomato, null);`

"tomato " is name of image you want to scale. and (100,200) parameters specifies width & height of scaled image.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Increase the size of JLabel or decrease the size of image to in JLabel.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply .... I cannot increase jlabel size so i need to resize image . I have gone through following link [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/)   .. is that I need to do ?

Comment: @Sachin: Yes you can do like on link. For more help on resizing image in java read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to resize the image to fit the JLabel, or increase the size of the JLabel

Comment: : Thanks for your reply .... I cannot increase jlabel size so i need to resize image . I have gone through following link [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/)   .. is that I need to do ?

Comment: @Sachin, yes you can do that. You could also use any tool like Microsoft Picture Manager, picasa, etc to change the size of the image