# How do I resize photo during upload?

Tags: java, picasa

I would like to reduce size of photo before uploading to picasa using picasa java api.
How can I resize photo during upload with Picasa API?

Comment: By 'resize' do you mean change the Width x Height in pixels, or the byte size?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see in the API, photos has to be resized before the upload. Luckily, it is [easy to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library) in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) and [imgscalr](https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr):

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;
   
InputStream myPhotoInputStream = // new FileInputStream(file)
                                 // or FileItemStream.openStream(); from an HTTP upload
OutputStream outstream = ...
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( myPhotoInputStream );
int maxDimension = 1024;
image = Scalr.resize(image, maxDimension);
ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", outstream);
```

Unfortunately when you resize, you lose the EXIF metadata.  I have yet to find a library capable of simply saving this on read and restoring it on write.  Apache commons-imaging looked promising but seems unable to write a JPEG.