# Resize Image To Fixed Size

Tags: java, image-processing, image-resizing

I need a logic to re-size an image so that its always 320X240 or smaller and should maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize an image in Java - Any Open Source Library ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library)

Comment: What specific part of this are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) determine which side of the image is the larger one
2) if its width, calc: faktor = 320/width, else faktor = 240/height;
3) downscale the image by size.x *faktor, size.y *faktor.
```

example:

Given: image has 1024x640

```
1) its wider than high.
2) faktor = 320 / 1024 -> 0.3125
3) 1024 * 0.3125 = 320 (huh!)     
   640 * 0.3125 = 200.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ImgScalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/), library for java.  Has several quality and speed settings for conversion as well as automatically scaling it for you.

```
BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(sourceFile));
BufferedImage destImage = Scalr.resize(sourceImage, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, 320, 240, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
```