# Java JPanel resize Image

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to make a simple java game, where a big ball eats smaller balls. I did that. Now I want the big ball to "grow" when it eats smaller balls, but I don't know how to resize an image in Java. Thanks in advance!

MovableBall.java:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class MovableBall {

    private String craft = "ball.png";

    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int mx = 200, my = 150;
    private Image image;

    public MovableBall() {
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(craft));
        image = ii.getImage();

        x = 5;
        y = 5;
        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);
    }

    public void move() {
        x += dx;

        y += dy;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = -1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = -1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 1;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 0;
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

FoodBoard.java:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FoodBoard extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private Timer timer;
    private MovableBall ball;
    private Food[] foods = { new Food(), new Food(), new Food(), new Food(),
            new Food(), new Food() };
    private int B_WIDTH;
    private int B_HEIGHT;

    public FoodBoard() {
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        ball = new MovableBall();

        // WURRY important:
        setFocusable(true);
        // every 5 ms the timer will call the actionPerformed() method
        timer = new Timer(5, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        B_WIDTH = getWidth();
        B_HEIGHT = getHeight();
    }

    public void checkIfEaten() {
        Rectangle r3 = ball.getBounds();

        for (int j = 0; j < foods.length; j++) {
            Food a = foods[j];
            Rectangle r2 = a.getBounds();

            if (r3.intersects(r2)) {
                a.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (int i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
            Food f = foods[i];
            if (f.isVisible()) {
                g2d.drawImage(f.getImage(), f.getX(), f.getY(), this);
            }
        }
        g2d.drawImage(ball.getImage(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), this);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ball.move();
        checkIfEaten();
        repaint();
    }

    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            ball.keyReleased(e);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            ball.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're close - take a look @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html - you have an option of drawing the image scaled, which can simulate growth.  It may get pixelated though, so you may want to load a larger resolution image if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize an image like this,

```
Image new_image = old_image.getScaledInstance( new_width, new_height,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;
```

To make sure the ball does not exceed the maximum size,

```
if(prevImage.getWidth(null) >= max_width || prevImage.getHeight(null) >= max_height)
{
    System.out.println("MAX Size reached !");
}
else
{
    // increase the size
    Image new_image = old_image.getScaledInstance( new_width, new_height,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I wrote `Image prevImage = ball.getImage();
    ball.setImage(prevImage.getScaledInstance(
      prevImage.getWidth(null) + 10,
      prevImage.getWidth(null) + 10, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));`
inside the if of checkIfEaten(), and it results in the ball getting bigger forever. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You can check if the image has reached a maximum size and then stop increasing its size. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why it keeps executing the code inside the if?

Comment: It should do that till it reaches he maximum size.

Comment: I'll have to find a way for it to no be called endlessly. Otherwise it will always eat one ball, grow, and never grow again, cause it reached its max size. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Image object, you really don't need to worry about resizing it, just use

```
yourImage.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

You would want to change the newWidth/newHeight parameters, but other than that, you should be good to go! You can read a lot more [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895829/resizing-image-in-java)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! I put this in `checkIfEaten()` : `Image im=ball.getImage();
    im.getScaledInstance(im.getWidth(null)+5,im.getHeight(null)+5,im.SCALE_DEFAULT);`
But it doesn't do anything. Am I writing it in the wrong place? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I am not used to this part of Java, but with what I do know, im.SCALE_DEFAULT isn't right. The SCALE_DEFAULT is a defined variablee in the Image class, and so when you use it, you have to do Image.SCALE_DEFAULT and it should work. Also, when doing getWidth(), I don't think you have to put the null, but that isn't going to hurt your game.

Comment: The problem was that, once I scaled it, I didn't set it as the ball's image. Thanks for your response :) I'm now facing the problem I commented in Rustagi's answer :P

Comment: you're very welcome :) but don't your resizing code in the for loop because that is most likely why it is constantly resizing itself.

Comment: Thing is, it shouldn't be called always, I wrote it inside the if. I'm stuck, I don't know where to put the ball's method grow. I don't know much about programming, but is it right if I define an event for each food-ball, "visibilityChanged" or something like that, and call the ball's method grow from there?