# Resize image with JFrame window resize in java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have 10 images in one JPanel in JFrame.
I want to resize all these images when user resize the JFrame window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [resizing image in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895829/resizing-image-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a GridLayout to display the images. The grid will resize as the frame is resized.
2. Use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) to display the Icon on a JLabel. The Icon will automatically resize itself.

Comment: @hiren, you should "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.