# Resizing image without keeping aspect ratio

Tags: java, image-resizing

I want to be able to resize my icons so that I can change the aspect ratio. I have the image of a rectangle and I want to be able to stretch it to any size, but when I resize it, it fills the empty space with padding instead of stretching it.

I used [SVGIcon](http://mcc.id.au/2005/04/SVGIcon.java) to create the icon but it keeps the aspect ratio when resized. I also have a .png of the rectangle.

How do I resize an icon without keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resizing image in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895829/resizing-image-in-java)

Comment: @pczeus `getScaledInstance` wouldn't be my first choice - FYI [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Comment: Maybe have a look at [imgscalr](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr)