# How to rescale image in java?

Tags: java, image, processing

I need to have an image at a different size as it is too small because I made it a pixel art, I didn't use an image editor to resize, as it would make it blurry. I need to resize it to fit the window.

My code is:

```
PImage logo;
int logoX = 250;
int logoY = 250;

void setup()
{
  //Canvas
  size(500, 610);

  //Background
  background(143, 132, 205);

  //Create the logo
  logo = loadImage("Tetris Java.png");
  image(logo, logoX, logoY);
}
```

I don't need exact dimensions, but they would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Deco, to make easier for experts to find your questions please add the correct tags for your question. Java has a lot of image processing libraries. Best of luck

Comment: [Java - resize image without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745147/java-resize-image-without-losing-quality/36367652)

Comment: Abra this doesn't help, and also Aboodz Idk what tags to use.

Comment: Deco you have a lot of methods here that we don't know what they're for. For example "loadImage" is that from a library, or is that a method that you wrote? Also, do you currently display the image? What is wrong with it if so.

Comment: your question is answered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5896284/3021180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you're using processing since it has a PImage. If you want a resized version of your image.

```
PImage logoScaled = new PImage( logo.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT) );
```

That should give you a scaled version. Also when you call `image(logo, logoX, logoY)`, there is a 5 argument version where you can specifiy the dimensions.

```
image(logo, logoX, logoY, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
```

These are two different ways. If you are using processing then you should add the tag, and you might get better help.