# change image size in java

Tags: java, image-resizing

I need to resize an image to 100*100 Aspect ratio in order to create an icon. i am using `java.awt.Graphics2D` for the same.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class FileResizeService {

    public File resizeImage(File file, String fileExtension) throws IOException {
        int imageWidth=100;
        int imageHeight=100;
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
        BufferedImage drawImage = drawImage(originalImage, type, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        ImageIO.write(drawImage, fileExtension, file);
        return file;
    }

    private BufferedImage drawImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, null);
        g.dispose();
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        return resizedImage;
    }
}
```

Above code resizes a high resolution image of size **5mb** to an image of **100*100** aspect ratio, but the image size still remains the same(i.e., **5mb** in this case), which is too much for an icon. i want the resized image to be in some kilobytes.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895829/resizing-image-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895829/resizing-image-in-java)