# Best Image Scaling Library

Tags: java, image-processing, image-resizing

I have searched and found a few image scaling libraries for Java. But not sure which one to go with. I need to generate thumbnails from the image uploaded by server.

It would be great if you can tell which one's good and bad.

The list I have is:

- JMagick
- im4java
- Thumbnailator
- java-image-scaling
- JAI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my private projects, I don't use any specific library, the functionality provided for Java gives decent results for me. If you just want to do image scaling, then a complete image processing library would be too heavyweighted.

I use the code snippets given in http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/ which works quite well.

Answer (score 13):

For my simple needs, [Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator) was perfect. Small lib; fluent, clean, well-documented API.

In my case, it was just `"net.coobird" % "thumbnailator" % "0.4.8"` dependency and:

```
//..
Thumbnails.of(originalFile)
      .size(300, 300) 
      .toFile(thumbnailFile)
//..
```

and *done*. Basically it’s a friendly wrapper on top of the Java 2D APIs. Useful for specific (thumbnailin') needs; no learning curve.

---

Unless you really need to do some heavy-lifting with images, I'd be wary of depending on an external binary (ImageMagick and wrappers like JMagick), which would add complexity and moving parts into the setup. Especially if your stack is something like mine: Scala/Java app running on Heroku. There’s stuff like `heroku-buildpack-imagemagick-cedar-14`, yes, but a simple dependency bundled with the app is infinitely cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

Java API to generate thumbnails is not good enough if you need high quality thumbnails.

To generate high quality thumbnails use a framework like the ones you have listed. I have tried ImgScalr (https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr) and Thumbnailator. 
With my microbenchmark tests (cannot really be used for general purpose conclusions) Thumbnailator is faster - though not by a lot, and easier - especially when generating thumbnails with transparency.

I also trying out JMagick but running into issues just compiling the code and setting it up. Also a little worried about running into issues later with a framework whose basic code is written in a language I don't understand at all - C.

You might also find useful the discussion here: [How can I resize an image using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library)