# How to resize an image before storing using tapestry5

Tags: java, tapestry

I am using tapestry5 framework, in which I am using uploadedFile component which is returning me a file which is type of an image.

Now I want to resize that image to 20 x 20, irrespective of the type of the image.

Is there any way with Java API or with Tapestry5 framework to achieve this?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library

Answer (score 2):

This is not functionality that is part of Tapestry, or every likely to be.  The Java2D API has more than sufficient support for converting byte streams into images, rescaling them, and storing them back out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
```