# Resize image java with Scalr, Incorrect output image, grey

Tags: java, image, resize, imgscalr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize an image in Java - Any Open Source Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/resize-an-image-in-java-any-open-source-library)

I wish I could resize the image just before recording! I tried several times but without success. Could you tell me the procedure. I would like to use imgscarlr or better. thank you

```
private static void getImages(String src,String Name) throws IOException {

    String folder = null;

    //Exctract the name of the image from the src attribute
    int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");


    if (indexname == src.length()) {
        src = src.substring(1, indexname);
    }

    indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    String name = src.substring(indexname, src.length());

    System.out.println(name);

    //Open a URL Stream
    URL url = new URL(src);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( folderPath+ name));

    for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {

        out.write(b);
    }


  BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(folderPath+name));
    BufferedImage scaledImage = Scalr.resize(originalImage, 200);
    ImageIO.write(scaledImage, "jpg", new File(folderPath+name));
    }
    }
```

I'ts ok but according to the pictures, I have a problem with sampling the gray part !!!

Comment: Could you please post only the code that deals with the image? All the file handling is not important.

Comment: BTW - DYM [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) (only one 'r')?

Comment: error-->Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at DownloadImages.getImages(DownloadImages.java:145)
 at DownloadImages.main(DownloadImages.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't load standard profile: GRAY.pf
 at java.awt.color.ICC_Profile$2.run(ICC_Profile.java:931)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.getStandardProfile(ICC_Profile.java:924)
 at java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.getDeferredInstance(ICC_Profile.java:1071)

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to "load" the image first, take a look at [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) API for more details, after that, depending on your needs, it's relatively simple to scale the image

**UPDATE**

[Reading image from URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

[Image scaling API](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/)

[Multi-step, hi-quality scaling](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Comment: *"it's relatively simple to scale the image"*  Not really 'easy' for an animated GIF.

Comment: thank you for your reply, could you give me an example of my code for me to understand the process

Comment: @AndrewThompson everything is relative ;), what you and I find relatively simple, others would find relatively hard...besides, you uses animated GIFs these days ;P (everybodies a critic today +1 for keeping me on my toes)

Comment: I was about to add a wink to my first comment, but resisted.  ;)  (..OK, I feel better now.)

Answer (score 0):

I had forget `out.close();` now it's work