# How to resize/rescale an image in Java

Tags: java, image, resize, bufferedimage, scaling

How would I resize a Java Image so that its size would be 1000 by 1000 px.
It would be cool if it's like 1-3 lines of code. Thanks!

Comment: The LoC constraint is oddly funny. Anyhow. This is not a coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resize an image using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/how-can-i-resize-an-image-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It works for me:

```
Image yourResizedImage = yourImage.getScaledInstance(YOUR_WIDTH, YOUR_HEIGHT,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH) ;
```

Comment: When i try to do the Graphics.drawImage it doesent work after i rote your line of code? o.o

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(1000,1000,BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)im.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(oldImg, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, null);`

At the end of this im will have the scaled image