# Java: Resize image doesn't work

Tags: java, resize

I do not know why this method does not work to resize an image. No errors occur (I have an exception if so):

```
   private static void resizeImage(int width, int height) {
        try {
            BufferedImage rawImg = ImageIO.read(new File("%imgg%.png"));
            int gamlaWidth = rawImg.getWidth();
            int gamlaHeight = rawImg.getHeight();
            BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(width, height, rawImg.getType());
            Graphics2D g = rawImg.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(rawImg, 0, 0, 114, 114, null);
            g.dispose();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ett fel uppstod:\n" + e, "Felmeddelande", 0);
        }
    }
```

Why doesn't this code change anything? I want the size to be 114x114.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use this code to resize an image.

```
Image smallerImage = null;
ImageIcon smallerImageIcon = null;
public void resizeImage(int width, int height, String image)

{
    ImageIcon originalImage = new ImageIcon(image);
    smallerImage = originalImage.getImage().getScaledInstance(width,height,0);
    smallerImageIcon = new ImageIcon(smallerImage);
}
```

Using this method if you wanted an image `%imgg%.png` to be 114 by 114 you would call the method like so

```
resizeImage(114, 114, "%imgg%.png");
```

With your code I believe the problem might be where you set it to 114 by 114 since that size is different to the scaled size.

Try

```
BufferedImage createResizedCopy(Image originalImage, int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight, boolean preserveAlpha)
{
    System.out.println("resizing...");
    int imageType = preserveAlpha ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
    BufferedImage scaledBI = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, imageType);
    Graphics2D g = scaledBI.createGraphics();
    if (preserveAlpha) {
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    }
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null); 
    g.dispose();
    return scaledBI;
}
```

**Use**

```
ImageIcon originalImage = new ImageIcon("%imgg%.png");
Image resizedImage = createResizedCopy(originalImage.getImage(),114,114,true);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/how-can-i-resize-an-image-using-java?rq=1)

Comment: But how do I replace the old image with the new, resized image?

Comment: @Stardox edited it so you declare the image before the method then run the method and after just call the correct variable

Comment: @Stardox I also added how to use the second method