# Java: looking for a better resize method

Tags: java

I wrote this little resize method to scale .png pictures:

```
    public BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType());
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newH, newW, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g.dispose();
    return dimg;
}
```

I want to make my .png picture at least 8 times bigger, but this fcks up the resolution of the image. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this :

```
BufferedImage createResizedCopy(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH)
{
    BufferedImage scaledBI = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = scaledBI.createGraphics();
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, null); 
    g.dispose();
    return scaledBI;
}
```

Or go see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244164/how-can-i-resize-an-image-using-java) , an other people have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do if you wish to is use the Image.getscaledinstance then render it. For example

```
resizedimage = image.getScaledInstance(newW, newH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
```

Only thing is you would have to change you method to work with a Image instead of a BufferedImage but that is easily done.